# WARN/AudioFlinger(33): write blocked for 76 msecs, 7773 delayed writes, thread 0xb3f0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have created an intent service to start the music for my app in the background.

It is working, but my log-cat is flooded with the messages:

09-14 16:46:30.117: WARN/AudioFlinger(33): write blocked for 76 msecs, 7773 delayed writes, thread 0xb3f0
and nothing else is getting Logged.

Here is my IntentService:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MusicService extends IntentService {

    MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    private OnErrorListener mErrorListener;

    public MusicService() {
        super("MusicService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.


    }   

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)

    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mPlayer.start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);


    }

    @Override

    public void onCreate ()

    {
        super.onCreate();
      //  try{
            mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        //}catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        //}catch (IllegalStateException e ) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        //}

        if(mPlayer!= null)
        {
            mPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
            mPlayer.setVolume(100,100);
        }


    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onPlayError();
            return true;
        }

    });


    }

    private void onPlayError() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "music player failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        if(mPlayer != null)
        {
            try{
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.release();
            }finally {
                mPlayer = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes and as looping is set to true.It is playing it nonstop

Comment: I get the same thing in my log file, but it doesn't seem to interfere with anything.

Comment: Though it does not interfere with anything but  looks like this blocks other messages getting printed in logs.

Comment: Well, if you figure something out let me know!  It does seem to block things temporarily, but I wonder if this is just an artifact of the emulator.

Comment: @Alan earlier I thought that this message is due to looping of the music but this is not so.I have modified the code by using service instead of intent service.Now I need to pin down this problem.My Initial guess is may be the music service is blocking something but why and what needs to be found out

Comment: Mine is also a plain Service.

Comment: I have this problem and I have not messed with audio or even the media namespace.  I am using Phonegap though, however it doesn't seem to cause any immediate problems.

Answer (score -3):

Permissions are needed. Put these in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />
```

I tested it under android emulator 2.2 so my minSdkVersion is 8.

Comment: **This is just plain wrong.**  If one of these permissions were needed and missing, it would not be audioflinger complaining it had been delayed, but rather the app would crash or part of its functionality would fail.

Comment: Agreed with Chris, these permissions are *not* needed for *playing* audio!

Comment: These are not needed for playing audio at all; They read/write to external storage and can mount/unmount file systems! I already flagged this answer yet it is labeled as "disputed". It seems to me that they can't see a wrong answer when the community sees one...